# LaTeX Fonts with fontspec-package

Tags: fonts, luatex, fontspec, filesystem-access, texmf-local

Today i figured out how to use system-installed-fonts with the `fontspec`-package and LuaLaTeX. But i can't figure out how to use fonts, that are installed in my `texmf`-tree!

The `fontspec`-Manual says (p. 10), that LuaLaTeX will see fonts installed in my `texmf`-tree and i can enter the name via a human readable-string (eg. Latin Modern Roman) or the filename (eg. ec-lmr10.tmf).

Even though i have confirmed that this file (and hence the font) is installed on my system in my `texmf`-tree, i can't get it to compile! I always get a

```
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!
! fontspec error: "font-not-found"
!
! The font "ec-lmr10.tfm" cannot be found.
!
! See the fontspec documentation for further information.
!
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................

l.13 \setmainfont{ec-lmr10.tfm}

?
```

Am i getting something wrong?
How can i use LaTeX-fonts with fontspec and LuaLaTeX?

Comment: you can not load tfm fonts via fontspec (latin modern is available as OpenType, and is the default font in lualatex so you do not have to do anything at all toi get latin modern)

Comment: What is wrong with `\usepackage{lmodern}` if you want to use these fonts if not using the default ones?

Comment: The question wasn't specifically about Latin Modern, it was about fonts in the texmf-tree! So, in general i would be better of with installing the desired font manually and using it like a system-font?

Comment: @TimHilt The file name is `lmroman10-regular.otf` (for 10 pt)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

fontspec is made for Open-Type-Fonts, that's why the `.tfm`-file didn't work. Also, @JosephWright pointed out the right name for the mentioned Latin Modern Roman font which i can therefore use with fontspec.

When i may want or need a certain font, `.ttf` or `.otf` would be the best format for fontspec to deal with. Such fonts can be found with

```
fc-list | grep <font-name>*.ttf
fc-list | grep <font-name>*.otf
```

for system-installed-fonts or

```
find /usr/share/texmf-dist/fonts/ -name <file-name>.ttf
find /usr/share/texmf-dist/fonts/ -name <file-name>.otf
```

for fonts in my `texmf`-tree.

If some font is not installed in my system or not available in the desired format through the tex-installation, there's the possibility to install the font via a package or put the matching `.ttf` / `.otf` file in `.fonts` and run `fc-cache -f -v` to update `fc-list`.

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
foo
\end{document}
```

running with current `lualatex` from TeXLive creates a document with the icluded Latin Modern:

```
$ pdffonts zzz2.pdf 
name                      type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------- ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- --------- 
NAGORB+LMRoman10-Regular  CID Type 0C       Identity-H       yes yes yes      4  0
```